# Ionic2 : working with SQLite, Ionic Serve

Tags: sqlite, browser, ionic2, ionic-serve

I am working with SQLite and Ionic2. So far so good. However, I can't seems to make it work while browsing it with Ionic Serve.
To put in the scenario: sometimes I need to make a quick layout adjustment / design which can be very nice if I could use browser to check instead of build and put on the emulator / devices.

Any idea how to make an SQLite work in web browser?
If it is not possible, any better alternative / approach.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite plugin doesn't support browser but you could either mock your SQLite using [ionic-native-mocks](https://github.com/chrisgriffith/ionic-native-mocks/tree/master/src/%40ionic-native-mocks/plugins/sqlite) or setup a different project without any plugins and design your pages there. A good example about mocking could be this [blog](https://www.techiediaries.com/mocking-native-sqlite-plugin/).